# SAS: join two table and keep the number of row

Tags: sql, join, sas

I want to join two tables by a variable `id`, but in my first table, there are some identical rows, and also, the number of rows for each `id` in those two tables are not the same. For example,

table1:

```
id        product
001        24
001        24
001        03
002        61
```

table2:

```
id        product      date          reference
001          24      01jun2015          1
001          24      01jun2015          2
001          24      01jun2015          3
001          03      05jun2015          4
002          61      06jun2015          5
```

Now I want to join those two tables by keeping the number of rows of table1 and to get the following table:

```
id        product      date          reference
001          24      01jun2015           1
001          24      01jun2015           2
001          03      05jun2015           4
002          61      06jun2015           5
```

There are 3 rows of id 001 in table2, but I only want to join the first 2 rows of id 001 with table1. I tried to use the `inner join` but the result have more than 4 rows.
Here is my code:

```
proc sql;
create table fusion as
select
   A.*,

   B.date,
   B.reference

   from table1                      A
   inner join
   table2                           B

   on A.id=B.id and A.product=B.product;
quit;
```

Hope to get your answers soon, thanks in advance!

Comment: It'd help if you explain the logic behind desired joining. Should having multiple occurrences of the same record in table2 affect somehow the result? Do these duplicated records in table2 always have the same `date`? If "no" and "yes" then just de-duplicate table2 as @dashnik suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your advides. I have updated the problem by adding a new variable `reference` in table2, so there is no rows which are exactly identical in table2.

Comment: Ok, but rows 1-3 are still duplicates from the standpoint of your joining process. You don't use `reference` field for anything in this task, right? So again, either delete duplicates or use `distinct` as in @KwstasMost comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** So the idea is that you want to pull in the first observation from `table2` for the first observation in `table1` with the same `id-product`, the second observation for the second, etc.  What you need to do here is more complicated.

First of all, for every `id-product` grouping, we'd need to assume that there are >= that number of records in `table2`, or else the merge would lead to a null value for your `reference` column in `fusion`.

What you need to do is add an extra `counter` column to each data table, and then merge on that field as well.  This will serve to pair off the records.  To do that:

```
proc sort data=table1; by id product; run;
proc sort data=table2; by id product; run;

data table1_wCount;
    retain counter;
    set table1;
    by id product;
    if first.product THEN counter=0;
    counter = counter+1;
end;

data table2_wCount;
    retain counter;
    set table2;
    by id product;
    if first.product THEN counter=0;
    counter = counter+1;
end;
```

Now, left join `table1_wCount` with `table2_wCount` on

```
A.id=B.id and A.product=B.product and A.counter=B.counter
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. It seems that I didn't explain the problem very well. Actually there is no duplicate row in table2. You can check the update of my problem.

Comment: What's the logic behind not joining on the third row of table 2?

Answer (score 0):

Remove duplicates in table2 (PROC SORT NODUPKEY), and then left join table1 and table2.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to create your own join reference. In the examples you have given this could be done as follows:

```
data table1;
 set table1;
 by id product notsorted;
 if first.product then joinref = 0;
 joinref+1;
run;

data table2 (index=(myjoin=(id product joinref)));
 set table2;
 by id product notsorted;
 if first.product then joinref = 0;
 joinref+1;
run;
```

Please note, I have assumed that your data is already in a specific order that you want, hence my use of the notsorted option on the by statement. You may however wish to index or sort your data by id and production which case you can remove the "not sorted" option.

I also added a compound index to the second table so that you can do a key join on id, product and your newly created joinref. To use this you would do the following:

```
data table3 (drop = joinref);
 set table1;
 set table2 key = myjoin / unique;
 if _iorc_ ne 0 then do;
  _ERROR_ = 0;
  date = '';
  reference = .;
 end;
run;
```

If you are not familiar with key joins, they are extremely efficient and a very neat way of keeping your first table in a specific order whilst matching data from another table based on an index in that table. The *iorc* is a return code from this match, that will be 0 when a match is found. If there is no match, you should reset any new fields coming across from your lookup table, as there is an implicit retain for data pulled across - i.e. if no match is found SAS will retain the values it found in the previous successful match unless you set those fields to null (this obviously doesn't include the indexed fields as they are already in your data and that you at looking up against - in the example above - id, product and joinref).

If you know that you will always have a match this "if *iorc* ne 0" statement is irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

Try it with left join.I think it will work this way .
The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: It will produce the same result  - 3x2=6 records for id=001 and product=24

Comment: Instead of removing duplicates i think you can use select distinct from table 2

Answer (score -1):

so the complete answer looks like to first delete the duplicate entries in table2 and then rerun your code.  If this is not the result you're looking for you need to explain the problem in greater detail

proc sort nodupkey data = table2 out=table3; 
    by id product;
    run;

```
proc sql;                                                                                                                               
create table fusion as                                                                                                                  
select                                                                                                                                  
   A.*,                                                                                                                          
   B.date                                                                                                                         
 from table1                      A                                                                                                   
 left  join                                                                                                                           
 table3                           B                                                                                                   

 on A.id=B.id 
 and A.product=B.product;                                                                                                
 quit;
```